# keras predict_generator save predictions in batches

Tags: keras, generator, predict

I have a set of files for which i want to make predictions. I have written a generator function which reads the file and creates array for input to predict_generator function. Currently the prediction_generator function returns a single array with predictions for all the files. Is their a way i can save/access the predictions of individual batches, because i later need to merge them with my original files.

```
def generate_prediction_array(pred_files):
    for file in pred_files:
        X = create_array(file)
        yield X
...
y_pred_prob = model.predict_generator(generate_prediction_array(pred_files), 
                                      max_queue_size=2,
                                      steps=len(pred_array_files))
```

When i look at y_pred_prob, it has predictions for all the data points in all the files. Instead i want to access prediction for each batch separately, so that i can merge it with my original file data.

Comment: what about using the `for` cycle instead of the predict_generator, storing all results into separate files, and later merging them?

Comment: can u please explain in detail